# How is the `cov.unscaled` for `lm` calculated in R

Tags: r

I just want to know how the the `cov.unscaled` calculated in R.
for example, if I fit a model:

```
fit <- lm(y~x)
summary(fit)$cov.unscaled
```

This should give me the answer, but how is it calculated?

Answer (score 0):

Its the coefficients which aren't scaled by the variance
From the documentation:

> cov.unscaled:  a p x p matrix of (unscaled) covariances of the coef[j],j=1, … p